# spark collect columns statistics for a specific partition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, partition, cost-based-optimizer

How can I tell spark to only collect column statistics for a specific partition?

```
WARN SparkSqlAstBuilder: Partition specification is ignored when collecting column statistics: PARTITION(myPart='myValue')
```

seems to ignore my filter of:

```
ANALYZE TABLE ${fullyQualifiedTable}
PARTITION(${table.partitionColumn} = '$partitionVal')
COMPUTE STATISTICS
FOR COLUMNS ${co.mkString(", ")}
```

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/103263/cannot-generate-stats-for-partitioned-hive-table.html might be related

Comment: Is it possible to calculate statistics on a temporarily registered table (i.e. a spark df filtered to desired partition (yes) and reliably store the statistics into the table properties of the original table (?).